# What is the appropriate regular expression for this pattern?

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a text file that contains a course catalog of all CS courses. The actual course itself is pretty simple to find because it is in the beginning of the line and begins with the course. The prerequisite is a bit trickier for me though. I can find the line that has the prerequisites but the prereq courses can be one or multiple and separated by commas and "and". There is also sometimes a line after the prereq sentence that contains other course names but not the prereq itself. Here is a sample of what the prereq file looks like:

```
CS 4213. Computing for Bioinformatics. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisite: CS 1173 or another programming course. Emphasizes computing tasks common in bioinformatics: variables, flow control, input/output, strings, pattern matching, arrays, hash tables, functions, access to databases, and parsing data from queries for common bioinformatics tasks. SQL, XML, and BioPerl. May not be applied to the 24 hours of required electives for computer science majors, but may be included for a computer science minor.
CS 4313. Automata, Computability, and Formal Languages. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisites: CS 3341 and CS 3343. Discussion of abstract machines (finite state automata, pushdown automata, and Turing machines), formal grammars (regular, context-free, and type 0), and the relationship among them.
CS 4353. Unix and Network Security. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisite: CS 3433. A technical survey of the fundamentals of computer and information security. Issues include cryptography, authentication, attack techniques at both the OS and network level, defense techniques, intrusion detection, scan techniques and detection, forensics, denial of service techniques and defenses, libpcap, libdnet and libnet programming.
CS 4363. Cryptography. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisites: CS 3341, CS 3343, and CS 3433. A course in pure and applied cryptography, with emphasis on theory. Topics may include conventional and public-key cryptosystems, signatures, pseudo-random sequences, hash functions, key management, and threshold schemes.
CS 4383. Computer Graphics. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisites: CS 2121, CS 2123, CS 3341, and CS 3343. An introduction to two- and three-dimensional generative computer graphics. Display devices, data structures, mathematical transformations, and algorithms used in picture generation, manipulation, and display.
CS 4393. User Interfaces. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisite: CS 3443. Study of advanced user interface issues. User interface design, human factors, usability, GUI programming models, and the psychological aspects of human-computer interaction.
CS 4413. Web Technologies. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisites: CS 3421 and CS 3423. Fundamentals of Web and component technology: markup languages, layout design, client and server side programming, database and Web integration.
CS 4593. Topics in Computer Science. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisite: Consent of instructor. Advanced topics in an area of computer science. May be repeated for credit when topics vary.
CS 4633. Simulation. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisites: CS 3341 and CS 3343. Design, execution, and analysis of simulation models, discrete event simulation techniques, input and output analysis, random numbers, and simulation tools and languages.
CS 4713. Compiler Construction. (3-0) 3 Credit Hours.
Prerequisites: CS 3341, CS 3343, CS 3841, and CS 3843. An introduction to implementation of translators. Topics include formal grammars, scanners, parsing techniques, syntax-directed translation, symbol table management, code generation, and code optimization. (Formerly titled “Compiler Writing.”).
```

This is what I have right now:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(CS [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^Prereq.* ([A-Z]* [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(line); 
    if (m2.find()) {
        System.out.println("Prereq: "+m2.group(1)+", Occurrences: "+m2.groupCount());
        //System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

And so far this gets all the courses and the first prerequisite or none if there are no prereqs for the course.

Sample Output:

```
CS 4213
Prereq: CS 1173, Occurrences: 1
CS 4313
Prereq: CS 3343, Occurrences: 1
CS 4353
Prereq: CS 3433, Occurrences: 1
CS 4363
Prereq: CS 3433, Occurrences: 1
CS 4383
Prereq: CS 3343, Occurrences: 1
CS 4393
Prereq: CS 3443, Occurrences: 1
CS 4413
Prereq: CS 3423, Occurrences: 1
CS 4593
CS 4633
Prereq: CS 3343, Occurrences: 1
CS 4713
Prereq: CS 3843, Occurrences: 1
```

So for say, 4313, I would like CS 3341 and CS 3343

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to match on? Course, and a list of prerequisite courses?

Comment: Yes I got "Pattern p" to match the Course, but "Pattern p2" only matches the first occurrence of the prereq course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easier with 3 patterns:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(CS [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^Prereq");
    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+ [0-9]{4}");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(line);
        if (m2.find()){
            final Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(line);
            while (m3.find()) {
                System.out.println("Prereq: " + m3.group(0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that does make things simpler though it still only gets the first prereq.

Comment: Actually it works now I must have forgot to put something. Thank you!

Comment: It actually ended up getting other courses after the first sentence that were not prerequisites but I solved it by splitting the prerequisite line with a  period as the delimiter and used the first element which contained the correct prereqs.